# DecimalType Issue - scala.MatchError of class java.lang.String

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.6.1 with Scala 2.10.5 built in. I am examining some weather data for which sometimes I have decimal values. Here is the code:

```
 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
 import sqlContext.implicits._

 import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
 import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
 import org.apache.spark.sql._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val rawData=sc.textFile("Example_Weather.csv").map(_.split(","))

val header=rawData.first

val rawDataNoHeader=rawData.filter(_(0)!= header(0))

rawDataNoHeader.first

object schema {
val weatherdata= StructType(Seq(
StructField("date", StringType, true),
StructField("Region", StringType, true),
StructField("Temperature", DecimalType(32,16), true),
StructField("Solar", IntegerType, true),
StructField("Rainfall", DecimalType(32,16), true), 
StructField("WindSpeed", DecimalType(32,16), true))
)
}

val dataDF=sqlContext.createDataFrame(rawDataNoHeader.map(p=>Row(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5))), schema.weatherdata)

dataDF.registerTempTable("weatherdataSQL")

val datasql = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM weatherdataSQL")

datasql.collect().foreach(println)
```

When running code, I get what is expected for the schema and sqlContext:

```
scala> object schema {
 | val weatherdata= StructType(Seq(
 | StructField("date", StringType, true),
 | StructField("Region", StringType, true),
 | StructField("Temperature", DecimalType(32,16), true),
 | StructField("Solar", IntegerType, true),
 | StructField("Rainfall", DecimalType(32,16), true),
 | StructField("WindSpeed", DecimalType(32,16), true))
 | )
 | }
16/09/24 09:40:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on localhost:56288 in memory (size: 4.6 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
16/09/24 09:40:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on localhost:39349 in memory (size: 4.6 KB, free: 2.7 GB)
16/09/24 09:40:58 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 2
16/09/24 09:40:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on localhost in memory (size: 1964.0 B, free: 511.1 MB)
16/09/24 09:40:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on localhost:41412 in memory (size: 1964.0 B, free: 2.7 GB)
16/09/24 09:40:58 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1
defined module schema

scala> val dataDF=sqlContext.createDataFrame(rawDataNoHeader.map(p=>Row(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5))), schema.weatherdata)
dataDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: string, Region: string, Temperature: decimal(32,16), Solar: int, Rainfall: decimal(32,16), WindSpeed: decimal(32,16)]
```

However, the last line of code gives me the following:

```
16/09/24 09:41:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): scala.MatchError: 20.21666667 (of class java.lang.String)
```

The number **20.21666667** is indeed the first temperature observed for a specific geographical region. I thought I had successfully specified for Temperature to be a Decimaltype(32,16). Is there a problem with my code or with even the sqlContext I am calling on?

As recommended I changed the dataDF to as follows:

```
val dataDF= sqlContext.createDataFrame(rawDataNoHeader.map(p=>Row(p(0),p(1),BigDecimal(p(2)),p(3),BigDecimal(p(4)),BigDecimal(p(5)))), schema.weatherdata)
```

Unfortunately, I now get a casting problem

```
16/09/24 10:31:35 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in your first edit was almost correct - p(3) had to be converted *toInt*

I created a sample csv file without headers:

```
2016,a,201.222,12,12.1,5.0
2016,b,200.222,13,12.3,6.0
2014,b,200.111,14,12.3,7.0
```

The results:

```
val dataDF= sqlContext.createDataFrame(rawData.map(p=>Row(p(0),p(1),BigDecimal(p(2)),p(3).toInt,BigDecimal(p(4)),BigDecimal(p(5)))), schema.weatherdata)

dataDF.show
+----+------+--------------------+-----+-------------------+------------------+
|date|Region|         Temperature|Solar|           Rainfall|         WindSpeed|
+----+------+--------------------+-----+-------------------+------------------+
|2016|     a|201.2220000000000000|   12|12.1000000000000000|5.0000000000000000|
|2016|     b|200.2220000000000000|   13|12.3000000000000000|6.0000000000000000|
|2014|     b|200.1110000000000000|   14|12.3000000000000000|7.0000000000000000|
+----+------+--------------------+-----+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Wow!!!! Fantastic!!!! Thank you Piotr R and Sakalya!!!! Works great!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are reading this data from a .csv file.And by default it takes the data as "Text/String" format.You can solve this problem by 2 ways 
1.Change the datatype in .csv file for the attribute temperature.
2.val temperatureInDecimal = BigDecimal("20.21666667")

I would recommened to use 2nd approach if you want to make your application from future perspective where .csv file can change.

Comment: why do you say maybe, give confident answer .. ask for more info about the problem in case info is not sufficient. this way your answer will be more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help... However a casting problem now emerges... See edit.
Thanks for the help once again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you know expected schema it is better to skip manual parsing and use proper input format. For Spark 1.6 / Scala 2.10 include `spark-csv` package (`--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0`) and:

```
val sqlContext: SQLContext = ???
val path: String = ???

sqlContext.read
  .format("csv")
  .schema(schema.weatherdata).option("header", "true")
  .load(path)
```

For 2.0+:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ???
val path: String = ???

spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .schema(schema.weatherdata).option("header", "true")
  .load(path)
```

Comment: Thanks @zero323... I am getting the databricks csv datasource package installed this week. Many thanks again!!!